# IrcDotNet connection error Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream when use SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-standard, irc

I'm trying to connect to an Irc server which gave me error:

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream.

**The C# code:**

```
_client = new StandardIrcClient();
_ircUrl = "irc.blabla.com";
_nick = "MyNick";
_port = 7021;
_useSsl = true;
_channels = new[] { "#test" };

IrcUserRegistrationInfo info = new IrcUserRegistrationInfo
{
    NickName = _nick,
    Password = "",
    RealName = _nick,
    UserName = _nick
};

_client.RawMessageReceived += (s, ev) =>
{
    write(ev.RawContent);
    _execute(ev.RawContent);
};

_client.Connected += (s, ev) =>
{
    write("Connected");
};

_client.Registered += (s, ev) =>
{
    _log.Debug("registered");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_inviteCommand))
    {
        if (_inviteCommand.IndexOf(":invite", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
        {
            _client.SendRawMessage($"PRIVMSG {_inviteCommand.Replace("invite", ":invite")}");
        }
    }

    _client.Channels.Join(_channels);
};

_client.ConnectFailed += (s, ev) =>
{
    write(ev.Error.Message);
    _client.Disconnect();
};

_client.Disconnected += (s, ev) =>
{
    _log.Debug("disconnected");
    write("Disconnected");
};

_client.Error += (s, ev) =>
{
    _log.Error(ev.Error);
};

_client.ErrorMessageReceived += (s, ev) =>
{
    _log.Error(ev.Message);
};

bool useSsl = _port > 0 && _useSsl;
if (useSsl)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
}

_client.Connect(_ircUrl, _port == 0 ? 6667 : _port, useSsl, info);
```

**EDIT**

I'm using **Net Standard** library so I *cannot* add SSL3 since it says is not supported protocol.

Comment: Can you supply with an actual IRC server, so i can test with ?

Comment: Can test on any irc with port >= 6697 and put true for useSSL flag in `Connect` method

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add Ssl3 `SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3` to your `SecurityProtocol`. You need to enable `Ssl3` security protocol also in your application.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

**Update:**
This issue occurs because the default set of `SSL/TLS` protocols that is used by `ServicePointManager` and `SslStream` was changed.

**Old value:** Ssl 3.0 | Tls 1.0 | Tls 1.1

**New value:** Tls 1.0 | Tls 1.1 | Tls 1.2

To work around this issue, update the server to `Tls 1.0, Tls 1.1, or Tls 1.2` because `SSL 3.0` has been shown to be unsecure and vulnerable to attacks such as POODLE.

Note If you cannot update the server, use `AppContext` class to opt out of this feature. To do this, use one of the following methods:

**Programmatically:** Must be the very first thing the application does because `ServicePointManager` will initialize only once.

Use the following code example in your application:

```
private const string DisableCachingName = @"TestSwitch.LocalAppContext.DisableCaching";
        private const string DontEnableSchUseStrongCryptoName = @"Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto";
        AppContext.SetSwitch(DisableCachingName, true);
        AppContext.SetSwitch(DontEnableSchUseStrongCryptoName, true);
```

[For more information : Cannot connect to a server by using the ServicePointManager or SslStream APIs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/3069494/cannot-connect-to-a-server-by-using-the-servicepointmanager-or-sslstre)

Comment: I'm using NETStandard and cannot add Ssl3 because I got: `The requested security protocol is not supported.`

Comment: @SnakeEyes What .Net Framework version are you using?

Comment: I have .NET Core 2.2
 application which uses .NETStandard 2.0 library (which has code provided above)

Comment: Please see the update in my answer. I hope that helps you.

Comment: I'm not using NET Framework ...so this didn't help me